# PHP Facebook api "Invalid UTF-8" json_encode error

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

We have a "json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument" error resulting when we try to do the following:

**CODE:**

```
$facebookdetails = $facebook->api(array(
    'access_token' => $fbtoken,
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => 'SELECT uid,name,last_name,first_name,
                 FROM user where uid=me()'
        ));
echo json_encode($facebookdetails[0]);
```

---

the facebookdetails contains this result when we print it using var_export

```
name' => 'ÐÐ³ÐÑÑ Ð°ÑÐ°Ñ', 'last_name' => 'ÐÐ°ÑÐ°Ñ',
```

---

in what encoding is Facebook returning these fields? and how should this be handled to properly send it using json_encode?